# how to get route distance in windows app

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, bing-maps

I am Creating a windows mobile app using **bing** map.I have latitude and longitude of my starting point and destination points. I am getting the aerial route but my requirement is to find the **routing distance** i.e the actual distance by road which is shown in my map between two points. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply for an api key to Bing's driving distance calculator. After you get your key, make http requests like so...

```
 "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?o=xml&wp.0=\\firstaddress&wp.1=\\secondaddress&distanceUnit=mi&key=\\yourkeyhere"
```

Here's a link with more in depth details...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx

Here's where you can get a key...
https://www.bingmapsportal.com/

I believe the distance can be parsed out like so...

```
String text = //http response
text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf("<TravelDistance>") + 16);
text = text.Remove(text.IndexOf("</TravelDistance>"));
double miles = Double.Parse(text);
```

Comment: my dear friend thanks for your support. I followed the steps and obtained the key. when i implemented the url given above i get an xml file in which i obtained travel distance. now the issue is how to fetch only the travel distance from this xml and show it in my app.

Comment: You could retrieve the 'json' content by setting the 'o' parameter to 'json', the answer would be smaller.
Then you use the JavaScriptSerializer or Json.Net to deserialize it to a 'dynamic' object in C# to access only the wanted property, travel time in your case.

Comment: Documentation on how to use the Bing Maps REST services in .NET can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx Also, be sure to encode/escape your location values, otherwise special characters will cause requests to fail. Take a look the best practices for Bing Maps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx